# Is there a tool to check the entire computer for errors?

Tags: 13.04, error-handling

Is there anything available in the world of Ubuntu to have the entire laptop/PC checked for errors?

I am wondering if there is an application that comes on the live CD or can be installed to run and find even the slightest error that causes problems in a computer.

Comment: What type of error are you looking for?

Comment: Well, anything.....I mean I cant identify the error. My laptop get slow...when more than 3 things are open. Linux before could handle a lot more. Video playback is slightly dodgy too. Video images get slow....the sound and image get de-scynronized. Simply....I have no clue why. that's why I'd like to run some sort of a test.

Comment: If I were you I would start checking your hardware. Your RAM, cpu, gpu and harddrive specifically. Maybe you could split your question up.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a memory test from the Ubuntu CD using Memtest+.  Another option that I use is the [Ultimate Boot CD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/).

Also there are tests that exercise the hardware at high speeds using a wide variety of number values or data patterns with results being checked for correctness.  These tests are called the [Linux Burn in Apps](http://www.roylongbottom.org.uk/linux_burn-in_apps.tar.gz).

Also available at Ubuntu Apps is the Cerberus Test Control System.

> The Cerberus Test Control System is a test suite for use by developers
>   and others to test hardware. It includes a modular test system that
>   allows you to build and integrate your own tests, however it comes
>   with a solid hardware stress-testing configuration.
>
> CAUTION: This package is designed to stress-test hardware components,
>   and as such can lead to crashes, data loss or hardware damage. Do not
>   use this package on machines that you can't afford to lose.

To install click [**Hardware testing/burnin suite** [image: Install comixcursors-lefthanded]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ctcs/).

A good site to look at is [Linux Stress Testing and Benchmarking](http://www.overclockers.com/forums/showthread.php?t=486495)

Hope that helps

<sup>Source:Ubuntu Apps</sup>

Comment: Too bad it won't test for applications misconfiguration or clogging the system.

Comment: @Braiam What won't test for applications misconfiguration or clogging the system?  There are more than 1 application listed:)